# Boto AWS: get service name from a resource id

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

Is there a way to get the Amazon service name which a resource id belongs with boto3?

I would expect something like:

```
service = client.get_service_name("i-0ff8943bb6c0db21c")
print(service)

OUTPUT:
EC2
```

or

```
service = client.get_service_name("subnet-007c14e3ae140c9d9")
print(service)

OUTPUT:
VPC
```

I dont find a way to get that.
Thanks.

Comment: Boto can't do that. Neither can AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API call to translate a Resource ID into a Service Name.